# Unpack two variables at a time in a list comprehension?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, list-comprehension, python-3.8

What is the simplest way to do this?

```
class a:
  def __init__(self):
    self.x = 1
    self.y = 2

a_list = [a(),a(),a()]

l = [a.x, a.y for a in a_list]
```

As a result, I want to get `[1,2,1,2,1,2]`.

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
>>> [i for a in a_list for i in (a.x, a.y)]
[1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]
```

Comment: The `for ... in ...` is just called a for clause, probably to avoid confusion with the `generator` type and generator expressions. (The corresponding construct in Haskell list comprehensions is, indeed, called a generator.) This is just a single list comprehension with two for clauses (which are nested by definition, so you don't really need to refer to the nestedness explicitly).

Answer (score 1):

*this is not list comprehension, however, is simple.*

```
import itertools
l = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable((a.x, a.y) for a in a_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't actually need the comprehension, don't care about defining `__iter__` and only ever going to have 2 attributes:

```py
class a:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1
        self.y = 2

    def __iter__(self):
        yield self.x
        yield self.y


a_list = [*a(), *a(), *a()]

print(a_list)
```

outputs

```
[1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]
```

This removes the need for a nested loop or `itertools` usage and is arguably more readable.

Also, the only thing that needs to change if more attributes are added to `a` is the `__iter__` implementation, and even that can be generalized:

```py
class a:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1
        self.y = 2
        self.z = 3

    def __iter__(self):
        yield from self.__dict__.values()
        # or return iter(self.__dict__.values()) which is a bit faster


a_list = [*a(), *a(), *a()]

print(a_list)
```

will output

```py
[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: [Bit faster](https://tio.run/##bZDBasQwDETv/grdbC9haZpLWdgvWRbjbpxWkDhGVkrT0m9P5fjQLq0OPoxmnganlV/n2D0l2raB5gkYp4AMOKWZGCik4Fkp5EAZznBRIKNXDGMPuz@HcTg61@ONnTu@@XEJ2VjdVCMFXihCiZv/ncV6VWqYCRxgBPLxJZjOngRQxNKlAvJpZ2ZBJqkyaK3VbfQ5g6@bPgzgHEYU/n7NVr2m5Pi7xNp7aRXp8V76EKlTv4ly/C/xE/mrVNgFlsyE0dT/Mvpy8MY28PNedVObNxCX6TnQuX2QsXaPJ8LIhuYl9oYPbegaaCWIXNZ1abftGw) to not pipe all values through an extra generator.

Comment: @KellyBundy Well, if your code depends on **that** optimization... :D anyway I updated my answer to include that, thanks

Comment: Well, I kinda focus on speed by default. But really I also think it's more "proper" to not needlessly wrap the values iterator in an extra generator iterator. Similar to how `a.sort(key=lambda x: len(x))` would be bugging me.